# Fetch and loop through the data from MySQL using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to loop through all rows in the database and display them to the user, but I'm only getting the first row in my output.

Here is my code::

**Query function:**

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo ->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count =$this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }

        }
        return $this;
    }


public function results() {
    return $this->_results;
}
```

**My query:**

```
$search = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM staff_info WHERE staff_id = ?",array(
Input::get('staff_id')));

if($search->count()){
if($search) {
    $search_result = $search->results();
    foreach ($search_result as $val) {
        $fname = $val->fname;
        $surname = $val->surname;
        $street = $val->street;

        echo '<div class="table-responsive table-bordered">
        <table class="table">
        <tr>
        <td><a href="index.php?ad=profile">'.$fname.'</a></td>
        <td><a href="index.php?ad=profile">'.$surname.'</td>
        <td><a href="index.php?ad=profile">'.$street.'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

The problem is -- I am getting only the first row even if there are more other rows in the database. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Its a wonder you are even getting 1 row from this!

Comment: i don knw wats wrong here.....any idea?

Comment: [PDO::query](http://www.php.net/pdo.query) & `public function query()` && `_query` To many `query's`????

Comment: i  didn't get you ....

Comment: See my code no confusing method names.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out the underscore.

In your query function you are storing output in `$this->_results`. You need to correct your variable name before looping. `$search->_results`.

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO  methods [prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php),execute() & fetchAll() or fetch(). Notice I have called my method `findAll()` so as not to confuse it with PDOs `fetchAll()`. The following code is based on my usage.

In Class

For all results

```
public function findAll($sql,$param) {
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    if(is_array($param)){
        $query->execute($param);//1 parameter
    }else { 
        $query->execute(array($param));// >1 parameters
    }
    $rows = $query->fetchAll();
        if($rows){
          return $rows;
        }
    }
  }
```

For one result

```
public function findOne($sql,$param) {
        $query = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        if(is_array($param)){
            $query->execute($param);//1 parameter
        }else { 
            $query->execute(array($param));// >1 parameters
        }
        $row = $query->fetch();
            if($row){
              return $row;
            }
        }
      }
```

Usage

```
$params=array(100,"AK");
 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id < ? AND state = ?";
 $rows = $dao->findAll($sql,$params);
 foreach($rows as $row){//Remove for 1 result
    echo $row['firstname'];
    etc.....
```

if you want to find one record only you can replace `fetchAll()` with `fetch()` in a new method and just echo without `foreach()`

Comment: i hav tried this way....but i still get one record.... but when i change the **$sql to "SELECT * FROM users";** i get all results

Comment: You must have only one result from your query. [See](http://gleniffersystems.net46.net/pdotest/dynamicFunction1a.php) for results from my database.

Comment: that  was wat i want...but i dont know y i just get the first row....can i see your database class???

Comment: Edited answer for one result.